# Is the interval $[-\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}]$ equal to $0$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Sorry if this is a dumb question, but does the interval $[-\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}]$ become $0$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$ or does it not quite get there...

In other words, does $[-\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}]$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$  leave a hole in the real line or does it become 0?

Comment: Are you asking about $\bigcap_{n = 1}^\infty [-\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}]$?

Comment: It gets there. The countable intersection of those intervals contains only $0$.

Comment: Just a notational comment, $0$ is a real number not a set of real numbers. So you should probably use the singleton set {0}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, $\left[-\tfrac{1}{n},\tfrac{1}{n}\right]=\left\{x\in\mathbb{R};\;-\tfrac{1}{n}\leq x\leq\tfrac{1}{n}\right\}$.

Consequence 1: $0\in \left[-\tfrac{1}{n},\tfrac{1}{n}\right]$ for all $n$.

Consequence 2: Given any $a\in \mathbb{R}$, $a\notin\left[-\tfrac{1}{n},\tfrac{1}{n}\right]$ for $n$ large enough (for example, for $n>1/|a|$).

Conclusion: The only number that belongs to all intervals is the number zero. In this sense, we can say that it become $0$.

Answer (score 2):

To say it goes to $x$ you must have some kind of limit definition. So this questions does not make sense. If you take the intersection then indeed it is the singleton $\{0\}$.

Answer (score 0):

This defines a sequence of sets
$$
A_n = [-1/n, 1/n]
$$
with
\begin{align}
\inf_{k \ge n} A_k &= \bigcap_{k=n}^\infty A_k= [0, 0] = \{ 0 \} \\
\sup_{k \ge n} A_k &= \bigcup_{k=n}^\infty A_k= [-1/n, 1/n] \\
\DeclareMathOperator*{\liminflim}{lim inf}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\limsuplim}{lim sup}
\liminflim_{n \to \infty} A_n &= \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \inf_{k \ge n} A_k = 
\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \{ 0 \} = \{ 0 \} \\
\limsuplim_{n \to \infty} A_n &= \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \sup_{k \ge n} A_k 
= \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} [-1/n, 1/n] = \{ 0 \} \\
\end{align}
and finally
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} A_n = \liminflim_{n \to \infty} A_n = \limsuplim_{n \to \infty} A_n = \{ 0 \}
$$

Comment: Note that this is using the (standard definition of [sets sequences limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit)

Comment: Oh, wow, I didn't know that you could define limits for sets. It's a bit annoying how $\lim_{n\to\infty}\{A_n\}\ne\{\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n\}$ in general, though. In fact, if the $A_n$ are all distinct, the former is the empty set.

Comment: Also, it doesn't play well with power sets — $\lim_{n\to\infty}{\cal P}(A_n)\ne{\cal P}(\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n)$ in general! For example, ${\cal P}(\lim_{n\to\infty}\{0,1,\dots,n\})={\cal P}(\Bbb N)$, but $\lim_{n\to\infty}{\cal P}(\{0,1,\dots,n\})={\cal P}_{\rm fin}\!(\Bbb N)$, the set of finite subsets of $\Bbb N$.

Comment: Like @BFreitas said "you must have some kind of limit definiton". There might be other definitons, maybe someone knows some alternative.

Answer (score 0):

It leaves a hole in the real line.  Since $0$ is in each interval $[-\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}]$, it remains in the intersection of all of them.